# vec:: in The Little Typer

Tags: types, racket, pie-lang

I am going through the Fifth Printing of *The Little Typer* with `racket` and `pie-lang`, and find the following conundrum. I have checked [the errata](https://thelittletyper.com/errata.html) but find no help, there.

While the example in Frame 6-25, pg. 134 works as shown:

```lisp
(claim first-of-one
       (Π ((E U))
          (-> (Vec E 1) E)))

(define first-of-one
  (λ (E)
    (λ (es)
      (head es))))

(first-of-one Atom (vec:: 'shiitake vecnil))
```

> ```
> (the Atom 'shiitake)
> ```

All of the following attempts fail with

> ```
> ; Can't determine a type
> ;   Source locations: ...
> ```

```lisp
(vec:: 'shiitake vecnil)
(vec:: (the Atom 'shiitake) vecnil)
(vec:: (the Atom 'shiitake) (the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil))
(vec:: 'shiitake (the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil))
```

(`(the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil)` does succeed by itself).

I do not know how to give my `(vec:: ...)` value more type information. While I'm able to write functions like `first-of-one` that manipulate `(vec:: ...)` values, it seems I cannot write constant values of type `Vec` other than `(the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil)`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All examples work iff wrapped in `(the (Vec Atom 1) ...)`, to wit:

```lisp
(the (Vec Atom 1) (vec:: 'shiitake vecnil))
(the (Vec Atom 1) (vec:: (the Atom 'shiitake) vecnil))
(the (Vec Atom 1) (vec:: (the Atom 'shiitake) (the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil)))
(the (Vec Atom 1) (vec:: 'shiitake (the (Vec Atom zero) vecnil)))
```